# Batch job to export data into CSV

Tags: csv, abap, jobs

I'm doing my first ABAP job and I don't have much experience so I need a little help.

What I want to do to create a batch job that runs every morning at a specific time, fetches data from different tables and exports it as a csv file. To create that batch job I can use transaction code SM36 or SM37.

But I need some help how to fetch the data?

Has anyone an example code that I can use or take a look at?

Comment: This is very basic ABAP reporting program stuff. Let us help you walk through this. 

-> Have you done any reporting programming before ?

Answer (score 1):

TheG is right, it sounds like you're trying to learn ABAP from scratch with no guidance. That's difficult but here are some basics:

There are three parts to this:
1. create a program
2. generate a file
3. schedule the job

For 1,
If you go to SE38, you can create a new report. You'll have to check with your colleagues about the namespace, but usually you just start the program with Z (which puts it in the 'customer' namespace).

In the entry box of SE38, you can type *DEMO* to pull up lots of sap-provided demo reports. The names usually give you a hint about what they demo and you can probably find one that **mentions creating a file**.

Once you create your own report through **SE38** by typing in the name and hitting enter, you can use **SELECT...INTO TABLE** or **SELECT ... ENDSELECT** to query the database tables. Highlight select and click the blue i icon to pull up SAP's internal documentation.

At it's most basic, you can use the WRITE statement to print out the rows and columns of your data.

Once you have your report running, then scheduling it with SM36 will be more self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic ABAP reporting program stuff. Making the report run as a background/batch job is the least of the concerns.  Let us help you walk through this.

-> Have you done any reporting programming before ?

-> Do you have the list of tables from which you want the data and do you know how they are linked ?

-> Do you know how often this report would be run and what would be the selection criteria required ?

-> Did you check with the functional team whether you want 'delta pull' or 'full pull' every time you run the report ?

-> Do you have the file share where you want to output the file ? Is it on the presentation server or the application server ? If not presentation server can you reason out why not ?

-> Did you confirm on the file name and how it should look ?

-> Do you know how to generate a CSV file ? If this is a 'production requirement' ,are there reusable frameworks for handling file operations in your company ?

-> Do you have the final format of how the CSV file would look ?

-> Did you verify with the functional team whether they want the output data in external format for some fields  ?

-> Did you check if there are date fields in your output and  what format you want it to be for consistency ?

If you are familiar with ABAP a little bit, explore answers for above, write a report and getting it running in dialog mode. Then revert back to us and we will help you on how to run it as a batch job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

-> No I haven't done any reporting programming.

-> I have the list of tables and the fields.

-> The report needs to be run once a day and fetch every active project

-> full pull, as every active project needs to be exported.

-> I think on the application server, as the report needs to run in the early morning.

-> I have the filename

-> I don't know how to generate the csv file.

-> I have the format how the csv should look.

-> Everything just needs to be exported as in the system

-> No date fields.

Could you get me started on writing the report please?

Comment: I am afraid this is hardly the forum or the best medium to get you started on writing simple programs :) There are many tutorials available a simple google search away. Go through them and give us a program with what you have written keeping in mind the above questions. 

Start from here :
[Basic Reporting](http://www.saponlinetutorials.com/sap-abap-report-programming/)

[SAP Example Demos](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35112)

I am not sure whether these are the best resources for newcomers, I should warn you. But go ahead and start writing a report based on them .

Comment: Hi TheG,

I created my table, gathered all the data and I can now write it to the screen.

How can I extract this data to a csv file in an auomated job?

Thank you!